# Box plot of hourly data in Time Series Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

How to group by a given frequency let say Hourly, and  create a set of box plot for one column in a time series data set ?

```
range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)

# Average speed in miles per hour
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
# Distance in miles (speed * 0.5 hours)
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25 
# Cumulative distance travelled
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()
df.head()
```

[image: Data sample]

How to group by a given frequency let say Hourly, and  create a set of box plot for speed ? A sample output is given below.

[image: Sample Expected output image]

Comment: Wanted to update the question, but instead I asked it separately. How to have one box plot for each day's each hour ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893658/how-to-group-by-a-given-frequency-let-say-hourly-for-different-dates-and-create

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you need, which gives you a box of speed during each hour of the a day:

```
#You need to reshape your dataframe with hours as column headers
df.set_index(df.index.hour, append=True)['speed'].unstack().plot.box()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Could you also help in making the Frame bigger. I  got a very small frame size graph

Comment: Add figsize=(10,8) as a parameter to the box method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use seaborn:

```
sns.boxplot(x=df.index.hour, y=df.speed)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Could you also help in making the Frame bigger. I  got a very small frame size graph

Comment: Do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))` and then pass `ax=ax` to `sns.boxplot`, or to `plot.box()` in Scott's answer.

Comment: Wanted to update the question, but instead I asked it separately. How to have one box plot for each day's each hour ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893658/how-to-group-by-a-given-frequency-let-say-hourly-for-different-dates-and-create