# How to group by a given frequency let say Hourly for different dates, and create a set of box plot for one column in a time series data set?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

How to group by a given frequency let say Hourly for different dates, and create a set of box plot for one column in a time series data set ?

A similar  problem and solution is below. But the below would group hourly data with regards less of date.  But the ask over here is, let say we have 10 day data , one Box plot for each day's each hour.
Hence we need **10 * 24** Box Plots in single frame.
Oder needs to be maintined as Day_1 Hour 1, Day_1 Hour 2 , .. Day 10 Hour 24

[Box plot of hourly data in Time Series Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893208/box-plot-of-hourly-data-in-time-series-python/56893455?noredirect=1#comment100333405_56893455)

```
range = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-01-10', freq='1min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range)

# Average speed in miles per hour
df['speed'] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=len(df.index))
# Distance in miles (speed * 0.5 hours)
df['distance'] = df['speed'] * 0.25 
# Cumulative distance travelled
df['cumulative_distance'] = df.distance.cumsum()
df.head()

sns.boxplot(x=df.index.hour, y=df.speed)
```

Comment: You say you have 10 days of data, but your sample has 365 days :-).

Comment: Thanks for catching and sorry for the mistake, I edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `hue`:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(30,8))
sns.boxplot(x=df.index.hour, y=df.speed, hue=df.index.day, ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you beautify its too conjested that and make it in order.. 
Like Day 1 Hour 1, Day 1 Hour 2 ... Day 2 Hour 1 ... Day 10 Hour 24

Comment: In that case, you are looking at the answer similar to the other question. Instead of `df.index.hour`, you pass `df.index.floor('H')`.

Comment: Wonderful, but the Index at the botom needs to be rotated since its too long and overlaps.

Comment: Add `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`.